# "AttributeError" when I installed pip with the use of "get-pip.py"

Tags: python, linux, pip

I tried to install pip-install in a new computer. I used 'python get-pip.py' and it reported an error"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'packaging'". It look like that there is something wrong with setuptools. How to solve this?

1. The python version: 2.7
2. System: ubuntu 14.10

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 20206, in <module>
    main() 
  File "get-pip.py", line 154, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 112, in bootstrap
    import setuptools  # noqa
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/extension.py", line 8, in <module> 
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 21, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'packaging'
```

Comment: Please consider adding additional information on the version of python and the full traceback of your error to your question

Comment: @cel I added some information, thanks